# Gawk partial match

Tags: awk, cygwin, gawk

My gawk script isn't matching all potential results, it's only matching one of them..

Example -

script:

```
gawk -F: "FNR==NR{a[$2]=$1;next} $1 in a{print a[$1] FS $2}" username.email.txt email.phone.txt > username.phone.txt
```

email.phone.txt - contains:

```
 email@email.com:phoneexample
```

username.email.txt - contains:

```
 user1:email@email.com
 user131:email@email.com
```

EXPECTED OUTPUT - should be:

```
 user1:phoneexample
 user131:phoneexample
```

instead it will only match 1 of the lines containing " email@email.com "

outputting -

```
 user131:email@email.com
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be better off when reversing files and fields:

```
awk -F: 'FNR==NR{a[$1]=$2;next} $2 in a{print $1 FS a[$2]}' email.phone.txt username.email.txt
user1:phoneexample
user131:phoneexample
```